# I can't open eps files even after installing ghostscript and editing the enviroment variables paths?

Tags: windows-10, inkscape

I read the other threads about this topic here and other tutorials on the web but I still can't open eps files.

[image: Capture of the error message]

[image: these are my Paths (environment variables)]

I hope you can help me, I have windows 10 and I also showed a capture of my paths above, I tried switching the bin and lib on different positions but I didn't work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks similar to this super old bug where `gssetgs.bat` specifies `gswin32` instead of `gswin64` https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=692089 . That has been fixed, but maybe you are doing something similar - how are you launching GS? Is your username really `andy_` with an underscore?